# Move "if" conditions to variables

Tags: bash

I am writting git hook file. I have following condition:

```
current_branch_name=$(echo $(git branch | grep "*" | sed "s;* ;;"))
merged_branch_name=$(echo $(git reflog -1) | cut -d" " -f 4 | sed "s;:;;")
release_branch_name="release"
develop_branch_name="develop"
master_branch_name="master"
hotfix_branch_name="hotfix/*"

if [[ ($current_branch_name == $release_branch_name  && $merged_branch_name == $develop_branch_name) 
        || ($current_branch_name == $master_branch_name && $merged_branch_name == $hotfix_branch_name) ]] ; then
#do something
fi
```

I would like to move conditions from `if` statement into a variable. I've done:

```
current_branch_name=$(echo $(git branch | grep "*" | sed "s;* ;;"))
merged_branch_name=$(echo $(git reflog -1) | cut -d" " -f 4 | sed "s;:;;")
release_branch_name="release"
develop_branch_name="develop"
master_branch_name="master"
hotfix_branch_name="hotfix/*"
is_merge_from_develop_to_release=$(($current_branch_name == $release_branch_name  && $merged_branch_name == $develop_branch_name))
is_merge_from_hotfix_to_master=$(($current_branch_name == $master_branch_name && $merged_branch_name == $hotfix_branch_name))

if [[ $is_merge_from_develop_to_release || $is_merge_from_hotfix_to_master ]] ; then
#do something
fi
```

It gives me an error for `hotfix/*`, but it works if the entire condition is stuffed in the `if` statement.
How can properly decouple conditions from `if` ?

**EDITED** (final version):

```
function checkBranches {
    local current_branch=$(echo $(git branch | grep "*" | sed "s;* ;;"))
    local merged_branch=$(echo $(git reflog -1) | cut -d" " -f 4 | sed "s;:;;")
    hotfix_branch_name="hotfix/*"

    [[ $current_branch == "release"  && 
        $merged_branch == "develop" ]] && return 0
    [[ $current_branch == "master" &&
        $merged_branch == $hotfix_branch_name ]] && return 0
    return 1
}

if checkBranches ; then
#do something
fi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really saving you lines but you could use a function:

```
check_branch () {
    local current_branch=$(echo $(git branch | grep "*" | sed "s;* ;;"))
    local merged_branch=$(echo $(git reflog -1) | cut -d" " -f 4 | sed "s;:;;")
    local release_branch_name="release"
    local develop_branch_name="develop"
    local master_branch_name="master"
    local hotfix_branch_name="hotfix/*"
    [[ "$current_branch" == "$release_branch_name"  && 
        "$merged_branch" == "$develop_branch_name" ]] && return 0
    [[ "$current_branch" == "$master_branch_name" &&
        "$merged_branch" == "$hotfix_branch_name" ]] && return 0
    return 1
}

if check_branch; then
    #something
fi
```

Will your branch names change frequently?  If not it would make more sense just to compare the variables against the strings: `release`, `develop`, `master`, `hotfix/*`.

Comment: thanks, good points. I updated my question with the final version. I also had to remove `"` and leave string `hotfix/` in variable to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

With `$(( ))` you can do arithmetic, it is not for string comparisons.

In general, you can convert

```
if cmd; then ...
```

to

```
var=$(cmd; echo $?)
if [[ $var ]]; then
```

This will execute `cmd` and then echo the return status of `cmd`, assigning it to `var`.

Comment: No, you'd have to use `if [[ $var = 0 ]]; then...`. Try `var=$(false; echo $?); if [[ $var ]]; then echo hello; fi` And unless you need to tell the difference between different falsy values (like 2, which often indicates an error), it's not really useful to store the exit value. Just put the code in a function and call it from the `if`.

Answer (score -1):

```
case $(git branch   |sed -nes/*\ //p
)$(    git -reflog 1|cut -d\  -f4
)  in      release:develop\
|          master:hotfix/*\
)          : hooray!
esac
```